# Can I intercept when any property is set on a javascript class object?

Tags: javascript

I want to log every time I set a property on a class. I know this can be done by adding get and set methods for each property explicitly. Is there any way to log when I set properties that I haven't written a setter for?

Comment: An actual `class`, or just an object? A class is something that you'd call `new` on, eg `new FooBar()`, where `FooBar` is a class

Comment: [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: constructor with arguments in oops try it.you want to intercept means what why just logger? what do you want to do?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I'm using a class calling new on. Do I need to somehow use Proxy within the constructor?